# Auto populating text box based on DGV selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have a DGV that has data populated through a .json file. When I click on a cell/row I would like to grab the data from the active row to populate a number of textboxes dynamically.

**Edits to explain:**
below is showing that I did indeed have my text bound to the dataset as Caius had shown me on previous question.

[image: Image shows textbox highlighted]
[image: image shows properties of same textbox.]

and a bit of code to show that the `datagridview` is linked to `dataset` `datatable`

```
        //json file holding all data to be parsed.
        string myDynamicJSON = File.ReadAllText(@"testLibrary.json");

        //the data
        ToolJson ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson> 
       (myDynamicJSON);

        //DataTable with something in it, do the binding
        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
        SBind.DataSource = tooldataSet.Tables["Tool"];
        


        //looks into File finds json fields, and assign them to 
        variables to be used in C# to create the rows.
        foreach (var datum in ToolData.datum)
        {
            string description = datum.Description;
            string vendor = datum.Vendor;
            double cost = datum.Cost;
            string serial = datum.ProductLink;
            string employee = datum.employee;
            string location = datum.location;
            bool returntool = datum.returnTool;
            int onHand = datum.onHandQty;
            int stockQty = datum.stockQty;
            int orderQty = datum.orderQty;
            string toolType = datum.Type;
            double diameter = datum.Geometry.Dc;
            double OAL = datum.Geometry.Oal;
            string productID = datum.ProductId;


            //Populate the DataTable with rows of data
            DataRow dr = tooldataSet.Tool.NewRow();

            // Fill the values
            dr["Description"] = description;
            dr["Vendor"] = vendor;
            dr["Cost"] = cost;
            dr["Serial #"] = serial;
            dr["Employee"] = employee;
            dr["Location"] = location;
            dr["OnHand"] = onHand;
            dr["StockQty"] =stockQty;
            dr["OrderQty"] = orderQty;
            dr["Return"] = returntool;
            dr["Diameter"] = diameter;
            dr["OAL"] = OAL;
            dr["Type"] = toolType;
            dr["Product Id"] = productID;
            


            //once all data is added to the row, add the row, and loop 
            untill all data is loaded.
            tooldataSet.Tool.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        //bind our dataset.table to the gridview
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;

        transactionEmployee_Box.Text = "";
        transactionSerial_Box.Text = "";
```

Comment: Can you please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can further help you?

Comment: sure one moment

Comment: Are the textboxes and dgv really bound through the same bindingsource? If not, add a binding source, bind it to the table, bind the controls to the BS, and fill the table.. it'll all work..

Comment: I figured it out using `active_Description.text = Convert.ToString(toolDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value)`

Comment: I'm not quite clear from the posted code how the data gets into the table.. I don't think it's Newtonsoft doing it? Also, you've shown a screenshot of you binding a textbox to a toolBindingSource, but you don't use that BS in code to attach to the tool data.. ? It seems like there's a break/not-joined-upness problem here

Comment: i didnt add everything in the first time. now i re edited it to show more of the code. should give some clarity

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own answer. The closest i had gotten to getting this accomplished was,
`active_Description.text = Convert.ToString(toolDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2]);`

but I never realized  I can add `.value` to the end of that and it works just fine.
`active_Description.text = Convert.ToString(toolDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value)` is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have misc. textboxes in my main form binded

Humor me; it'll take about 2 minutes to do this:

- make a new winforms .net framework project
- add a DataSet type file to it, open it
- right click in the dataset surface and add a datatable
- add two columns to the table
- switch to the form designer
- open the data sources window (view menu >> other windows)
- expand every node in the data sources window
- drag the table node to the form
- drag the two column nodes to the form
- run the app, bash 3 rows of data into the dgv with any random test data
- click randomly up and down the rows, and see the textboxes change..

..that's data binding!

Comment: you actually already answered my question last week on this, and helped me get where I am now. I know this exactly what you said last time. and it seemed to work last time. but for some reason it stopped working.  Is there a serious downside to doing what I did? seemed to work very easily, and its not complicating to do. (Neither is what you are saying I believe I could walk myself through it again). when the form loads initially it binds textboxes to first row which is nice but it doesnt update when user clicks about the form.

Comment: Hah, sorry.. I make so many posts a week I genuinely forget who I've told what - sorry if it was repeated info. "Any downsides" is quite a broad question to answer.. I think most devs who have gotten used to working in an MVC "keep your data in here.. show it via that control there.. and manipulate it via this thing over here" way would balk at "scrape some text out of a DGV cell value and put it in a textbox" because data lives in the datatable, not the grid

Comment: yea i figured you answer alot of stuff. i updated my question with some more content that points towards something went awry. I understand that its not the ideal way to do things but it does work for me. I just have such a hard time wrapping my head around OOP. Im reading a book currently called C# players guide. kind of different approach to presenting the information. but its slow going for me.

Comment: For an extreme example, it's a bit like saying "what's wrong with taking a screenshot of my textbox and OCR'ing it when I want the text out of it" ? - It'll probably work quite reliably, it's just "not as intended".. When there's a mechanism for keeping data in some place, and a whole ecosystem of stuff surrounding it for things like observing changes to it, I guess you either choose to use it, or ignore it.. It's a learning curve for sure (I spent months banging my head on certain parts of it), but it makes life easier once you know how it can boost productivity rather than get in the way..

Comment: fair point. Well. I'll revisit this at some point soon and see if I can get through and do it the "Proper way". in the meantime. thank you for the help on both occasions.